# Getting date value from DateTimeType element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, symfony, datepicker

I'm working on Symfony and trying to get date value from `DateTimeType` element using JavaScript : [image]

```js
var date1 = document.getElementById('debut').value;
alert(date1);
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date DE debut</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    {{ form_widget(form.datedebut,{'id':'debut'}) }}
  </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: You're mixing server side (Symfony/Twig) code with client size (JS) code. Check how looks generated HTML code in your browser, and then you'll know how to access these fields.

Comment: when i switch the twig code : '{{ form_widget(form.datedebut,{'id':'debut'}) }}' to <input type="date"> it works just fine . Aren't they the same date format?

Comment: No, JavaScript can't access twig elements only HTML DOM elements.

Comment: @Hamza It works when you change it to an element most likely due to your script executing before the elements are injected by the widget and when your script runs the elements does not yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this in form builder and add JS datepicker

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
// ...

$builder->add('date_created', DateType::class, array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    // this is actually the default format for single_text
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
));
```

Or refer this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html